# which version of servlet api is used in Spring MVC?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, servlets

Which version of the servlet api are used for each of the Spring MVC versions, and where can I find such information? I couldn't find them in the docs.

Comment: Just look at [Maven](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-webmvc) and the dependencies.

Comment: @Boris the Spider thanks! Any idea why they don't show up in mvn dependency:tree?

Comment: Look at the [pom](http://central.maven.org/maven2/org/springframework/spring-webmvc/4.1.6.RELEASE/spring-webmvc-4.1.6.RELEASE.pom) - `<optional>true</optional>`. In fact, if the servlet API were included in your build your servlet container would kick up a fuss, it's its job to provide the implementations at runtime - bundling the API will cause weird and wonderful problems.

Comment: @boris the spider Thanks!

Comment: Go w the latest version your app container supports, esp w Spring Security as it has some useful features

Comment: @NeilMcGuigan even if I use the latest version, isn't it no good if Spring Security was built against lower version?

Comment: @Yeonho Spring Security's behaviour is slightly diff depending on which servlet version you use. Esp wrt session fixation

Answer (score 8):

There is another way to find out about dependencies:

For the case that something (like Spring WebMVC) could be found via [mvnrepository](https://mvnrepository.com/) then you could lookup the dependencies there.

For example:

[org.springframework » spring-webmvc](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-webmvc)

Under: **Provided Dependencies**

```
--------------------------------------------------------------
|WebMVC     |Dependency                       |Min-Max version
--------------------------------------------------------------
|5.1.9      |javax.servlet » javax.servlet-api|4.0.1
--------------------------------------------------------------
|5.0.15     |javax.servlet » javax.servlet-api|4.0.1
--------------------------------------------------------------
|4.3.25     |javax.servlet » javax.servlet-api|3.0.1 - 4.0.1
--------------------------------------------------------------
|4.2.9      |javax.servlet » javax.servlet-api|3.0.1 - 4.0.1
--------------------------------------------------------------
|4.1.9      |javax.servlet » javax.servlet-api|3.0.1 - 4.0.1
--------------------------------------------------------------
|4.0.9      |javax.servlet » javax.servlet-api|3.0.1 - 4.0.1
--------------------------------------------------------------
|3.2.18     |javax.servlet » javax.servlet-api|3.0.1 - 4.0.1
--------------------------------------------------------------
|3.1.4      |javax.servlet » javax.servlet-api|2.1 - 2.3.3
--------------------------------------------------------------
|3.0.7      |javax.servlet » javax.servlet-api|2.1 - 2.3.3
--------------------------------------------------------------
|2.5.6.SEC03|javax.servlet » javax.servlet-api|2.4 - 4.0.1
--------------------------------------------------------------
|2.0.8      |javax.servlet » javax.servlet-api|2.4 - 4.0.1
--------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: can you please provide more details about where did you find the "Provided Dependencies" section on the maven dependency page?

Comment: For the example link you have to click on a version number - and then have a look at Compiled Dependencies ...

Comment: But did you write the table above by yourself after manually inspecting each version or did you generate it somehow?

Comment: I wrote it by myself after manually inspection each version.

Comment: Thank you for the information, that's why I was curious.. I hoped there's a tool which generates this, but this could be a good idea of something to be created

Answer (score 1):

Spring MVC 4 focused primarily on Servlet 3.0+ environments. 
The information is given in spring framework reference manual.

Comment: I was curios abot which exact version they used for building the library itself, etc.

Comment: Download Springs framework source and check with IDE.. May be you will get answer.

Answer (score 0):

its dependency scopes: "provided" @PowerStat, should not be considered as exactly dependency.

### https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-webmvc/5.0.0.RELEASE

```
1. Java EE 7 API level required in Spring's corresponding features now.

Servlet 3.1, Bean Validation 1.1, JPA 2.1, JMS 2.0
Recent servers: e.g. Tomcat 8.5+, Jetty 9.4+, WildFly 10+


2. Compatibility with Java EE 8 API level at runtime.

Servlet 4.0, Bean Validation 2.0, JPA 2.2, JSON Binding API 1.0
Tested against Tomcat 9.0, Hibernate Validator 6.0, Apache Johnzon 1.1
```

From official documents 
https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/wiki/What%27s-New-in-Spring-Framework-5.x#whats-new-in-version-50